# How do s3 replicas work?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am new to cloud computing and I was working on a research paper for s3 proactive replica checking. I have a few questions and I have tried and read many forums and research papers but I couldn't find answers anywhere or they may be too complicated for me to understand.

1. If I don't enable, cross regional replica for s3 storage, just created a new bucket, will AWS automatically create replicas for my storage anywhere?
2. Is there any Java code or tutorial available by which I can calculate the s3 replica checking time?

Comment: If you are trying to find information about the inner-workings of Amazon S3, you won't find any publicly-available information. AWS states that data is replicated in multiple data centers within a region, but doesn't go any further into defining how this is done, nor how replicas are health-checked. You also have no visibility into how quickly this is done.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not programming-related.

Answer (score 1):

AWS has great documentation on their services so that's the place to start.  This link should help:  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/DataDurability.html

To answer your first question, replication occurs automatically for all s3 objects in a given region and provides 11 9s durability unless you choose reduced redundancy storage.

Cross region replication is something you will have to enable and is not automatic.  As for java code to test replication time, I'm not aware of any.  However it seems you could do it fairly easily using the standard SDK and issue a PUT for an object and then time how long it takes to show up in the bucket of the region to which you have replicated it.  I suspect that timing will depend on your origin and destination regions, but from my experience I can tell you even replicating from a US region to an Asia region is quite fast.